# Do a infinite loop while downloading a file in c++?

Tags: c++, bash, download, infinite-loop

I want to download a html file, by using this bash command

```
system("wget -q -E -O  sample.html http://www.XXX.com");
```

sometime the file might huge, so I was thinking to do an infinite loop until the file is downloaded. Is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

Main Objective:

Download the html file, then proceed with the rest of the codes

I solve it myself. Can anyone close this question. I am terribly sorry

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, and chose as answer.

Comment: @ajreal:I already did. But I found the best answer => Ferrucio =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system()` will block until the command has finished executing. You don't have to do anything special to wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `popen` and a suitable mode of `wget` that outputs machine readable information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some kind of timer / delay for the loop (say check every second) to not fry that CPU :)

Answer (score 0):

you will not want to do an 'infinite loop' for something that isn't necessary to be 'software timed'. Instead, i'd do a loop where you Sleep the code until the download is finished (sleep periodically and check to see if finished, if not, sleep some more, if so, continue on). Using an infinite loop will suck up your CPU unnecessarily and you usually want to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is:

```
while(system("wget -q -E -O  sample.html http://www.XXX.com/")){
    ;
};
```

I know my answer is suck. Will try implement your guys answer later on. but I stuck again, I am posting another question here [Read file and extract certain part only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279200/c-read-file-and-extract-certain-part-only)

Comment: Did you need this while? @Ferruccio said system itself blocks until completed?

Comment: You are right... There is no need to use while loop. Thanks, was to busy do coding lol. And I though, nobody will answer my question lol